# Java program using switch case seasons of the year getting error

Tags: java, conditional-statements, switch-statement

I am trying out a program, below are the details

> Write a program to take a month number and print if it is summer,
> winter,rainy season Month number - `1` to `12`.  Let's assume  Winter:
> Nov, Dec, Feb, Summer: Mar, April, May, June, July, Rainy:
> July, August, Sep, Oct.
>
> Note: you can use default to handle rainy, and just 2 cases to handle
> winter and summer

**# Solution 1 - only testing the logic**

```
package java_cls;

public class switch {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int month = 6;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("January");
                System.out.println("Winter");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("February");
                System.out.println("Winter");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("March");
                System.out.println("Summer");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("April");
                System.out.println("Summer");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("May");
                System.out.println("Summer");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("June");
                System.out.println("Summer");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("July");
                System.out.println("Summer");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("August");
                System.out.println("Rainy");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("September");
                System.out.println("Rainy");
                break;
            case 10:
                System.out.println("October");
                System.out.println("Rainy");
                break;
            case 11:
                System.out.println("November");
                System.out.println("Winter");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println("December");
                System.out.println("Winter");
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

**# solution 2 - Actual solution**

```
public class ifelse {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        String summer = "March,April,May,June,July";
        String winter = "November,December,January,February";
        String rainy = "August,September,October";

        int month = 1;

        switch (summer) {
            case 1:
                System.out.printf("Summer");
                break;
        }
        switch (winter) {
            case 2:
                System.out.printf("Winter");
                break;
        }
        switch (rainy) {
            case 3:
            default:

        }
    }
}
```

from solution 2 I was not able to construct the final solution, any leads will be helpful.

Comment: Variable `Summer` is a `String`, and you try to compare it to `int`-values (`1`, `2`, ...). --- As an aside: In Java, variable names should be written in `lowerCamelCase` (`Summer` -> `summer`)

Comment: Having a `switch` statement with a single case or a single case that falls through to `default` are not really useful, unless you are expecting to immediately add more to them. What you are doing here is more like a series of unrelated `if` statements. Switches are supposed to replace multiple related `if` statements or an `if...if else...else` statement. You aren't even comparing "month" to anything, so you might want to read up on them. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html That even uses a similar example.

Comment: Let's go back to your first attempt: Have the names of the months in an array. Then, `System.out.println (monthName [month - 1])` before `switch`. Then, you can have `case` like this: `case 11: case 12: case 1: case 2:  System.out.println ("Winter"); break; case 3: case 4: case 5 ...`  (You might rather use `if` statements).

Comment: `switch case` doesn't work the way you tried in your 2nd example. Think of it like this: `switch (expr)` evaluates `expr`. Each `case` tests the result of the evaluation. Your `summer` in example 2 is similar to trying to test `"March,April,May,June,July" == 1`. That doesn't makes sense, since `summer` is a `String` and `1` is an `int` literal. The same objection applies to `winter` and `rainy`.

Comment: @Turing85, computerguy, Old Dog Programmer - Many thanks for the great explanation from one and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Write a program to take a month number and print if it is summer,
> winter,rainy season Month number - 1to 12 Let's assume Winter:
> Nov,Dec,Feb Summer: Mar,April,May,June, July Rainy:
> July,August,Sep,Oct
>
> Note: you can use default to handle rainy, and just 2 cases to handle
> winter and summer

There's no way to make it done using `switch`-statements with literally only `2` case labels, but Java allows to group case labels and associate the group of labels with a single statement.

So as *@Old Dog Programmer* has pointed out in the comments, you can create `2` groups of `case` labels (for `"Winter"` and for `"Summer"`), and caver the `"Rainy"` season using `default` label.

In order to do that you need to define an array containing the names of months, and then inside the `switch` refer its elements.

That how it might look like:

```
int month = // initalizing the month variable
        
String[] months = {
    "January", "February",                   // Winter
    "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", // Summer
    "August", "September", "October",        // Rainy
    "November", "December"                   // Winter
};
        
int monthIndex = month - 1;
        
switch (monthIndex) {
    case 0: case 1: case 10: case 11:
        System.out.println(months[monthIndex]);
        System.out.println("Winter");
        break;
    case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6:
        System.out.println(months[monthIndex]);
        System.out.println("Summer");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println(months[monthIndex]);
        System.out.println("Rainy");
}
```

I guess that's what you're required to do.

Just for informational purposes, here's a couple of more advanced options.

## [Java 14 `switch`-expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html)

`switch`-statement shown above can be written in a more concise way using `switch`-expressions (no need to repeat `case` and use `break` statements):

```
switch (monthIndex) {
    case 0, 1, 10, 11 -> {
        System.out.println(months[monthIndex]);
        System.out.println("Winter");
    }
    case 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 -> {
        System.out.println(months[monthIndex]);
        System.out.println("Summer");
    }
    default -> {
        System.out.println(months[monthIndex]);
        System.out.println("Rainy");
    }
}
```

## Map

Another option is to associate a Month with a corresponding season is to use a `Map`, this approach doesn't require resorting to conditional statements.

In order to make the code for generating a `Map` I've use Stream API and Collector `toMap()`.

The overall logic remains the same: map contains information about the `"Winter"` and `"Summer"`, the case with the `"Rainy"` season is covered using `Map.getOrDefault()` method.

Here's how it might look like:

```
public static final String[] MONTHS = {
    "January", "February",                   // Winter
    "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", // Summer
    "August", "September", "October",        // Rainy
    "November", "December"                   // Winter
};

public static final Map<Integer, String> SEASON_BY_MONTH =
    Stream.concat(
            IntStream.of(0, 1, 10, 11).mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(i, "Winter")),
            IntStream.of(2, 3, 4, 5, 6).mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(i, "Summer"))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

public static void displayMonth(int month) {
    int monthIndex = month - 1;
    
    System.out.println(MONTHS[monthIndex]);
    System.out.println(SEASON_BY_MONTH.getOrDefault(monthIndex, "Rainy"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since the resolution of your problem doesn't seem to need the name of the month you can do like this if you really want just 2 cases and a default on the switch statement

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int monthNum = 1;
            Season season = Season.getSeason(monthNum);
            if(season == null) return;
            switch (season) {
                case SUMMER:
                    System.out.println("Summer");
                    break;
                case WINTER:
                    System.out.println("Winter");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Rainy");
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

--

```
enum Season {
        WINTER(List.of(1, 2, 11, 12)),
        SUMMER(List.of(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)),
        RAINY(List.of(8, 9, 10));

        private final List<Integer> months;

        Season(List<Integer> months) {
            this.months = months;
        }

        public static Season getSeason(int num) {
            for (Season season : Season.values()) {
                if (season.months.contains(num)) return season;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

--
This one is only if you want to also print the months name

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] months = new String[]{
                "January", "February", "March", "April",
                "May", "June", "July", "August",
                "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        int monthNum = 12;
        Season season = Season.getSeason(monthNum);
        if (season == null) return;
        switch (season) {
            case SUMMER:
                System.out.println("Summer");
                System.out.println(months[monthNum - 1]);
                break;
            case WINTER:
                System.out.println("Winter");
                System.out.println(months[monthNum - 1]);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Rainy");
                System.out.println(months[monthNum - 1]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```